# How to select customer which has 0 sales (no records in order details table)

Tags: sql

This query already works if all customers included have sales records, If There is no order detail records for that customer, that customer doesn't even appear in the rowset returned in the following query. How can I make up a zero when that happens?
Thanks

```
select  c1.type0 AS type,  NULLIF(c.cnt,0) AS cnt from    
   (select ct.CustomerTypeName AS type0 from customer_type ct) c1    
     LEFT JOIN    
           (select '贵宾会员' As type0, count(c.CustomerCode) AS cnt    
                 from customer c INNER JOIN     


                (select c.CustomerCode, sum(od.NetSales) AS Sales from customer c
                  INNER JOIN orders o ON (c.CustomerCode = o.CustomerCode)    
                  INNER JOIN order_details od ON (o.OrderCode = od.OrderCode),  
                  VIPLevelUpParam v, ActiveParam a    
               where   a.ActiveID = v.LevelUpID  
               AND a.TableName = 'VIPLevelUpParam'   
               AND   TRIM(CAST(CAST(YEAR(c.MemoryDate) AS CHAR(4)) AS VARCHAR(4))) || '-' ||     
                     TRIM(CAST(CAST(MONTH(c.MemoryDate)  AS CHAR(2)) AS VARCHAR(2)))       
                       = '2013-11' 

                  group by c.CustomerCode, v.LevelUpAmount    
                  having sum(od.NetSales) >= v.LevelUpAmount)  c1    
                  ON c.CustomerCode = c1.CustomerCode   

    union       
     select '普通会员' AS type0, count(c.CustomerCode) AS cnt   
      from customer c INNER JOIN  
       (select c.CustomerCode, sum(od.NetSales) AS Sales  from customer c 
              INNER JOIN orders o ON (c.CustomerCode = o.CustomerCode)    
              INNER JOIN order_details od ON (o.OrderCode = od.OrderCode), 
                VIPLevelUpParam v, ActiveParam a    
                where   a.ActiveID = v.LevelUpID 
                  AND a.TableName = 'VIPLevelUpParam' 
                  AND TRIM(CAST(CAST(YEAR(c.MemoryDate) AS CHAR(4)) AS VARCHAR(4))) || '-' ||     
                      TRIM(CAST(CAST(MONTH(c.MemoryDate)  AS CHAR(2)) AS VARCHAR(2)))       
                      = '2013-11'  
                  group by c.CustomerCode, v.LevelUpAmount    
                  having sum(od.NetSales) < v.LevelUpAmount)  c2    
                  ON c.CustomerCode = c2.CustomerCode  
       ) c    
  ON c.type0 = c1.type0    
  group by c1.type0, c.cnt;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need just to use LEFT JOIN

In that snippets of code:

```
select c.CustomerCode, sum(od.NetSales) AS Sales from customer c
INNER JOIN orders o ON (c.CustomerCode = o.CustomerCode)    
INNER JOIN order_details od ON (o.OrderCode = od.OrderCode)
```

Try to use:

```
select c.CustomerCode, sum(od.NetSales) AS Sales from customer c
LEFT JOIN orders o ON (c.CustomerCode = o.CustomerCode)    
INNER JOIN order_details od ON (o.OrderCode = od.OrderCode)
```

Comment: select c.CustomerCode, NULLIF(sum(NULLIF(od.NetSales,0)),0) AS Sales from customer c
LEFT JOIN orders o ON (c.CustomerCode = o.CustomerCode)    
LEFT JOIN order_details od ON (o.OrderCode = od.OrderCode)
 group by c.CUSTOMERCODE          I can't get a zero out of NULLIF

Comment: Explain please in question more what you want to get.